# Java CheckStyle usage

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'd like to write my own Check using [CheckStyle](https://sourceforge.net/projects/checkstyle/) and incorporate this in my ant build.xml.  The documentation doesn't seem to provide detailed instructions on how to do so.  Does anyone have experience doing this, and if so, can they provide a `HelloWorldCheck` example along with the changes one needs in their `build.xml` to create a target that runs this?

[Here](http://checkstyle.2069334.n4.nabble.com/Custom-Checkstyle-Help-td3647968.html) is a reference to my question on their sourceforge mail dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for writing an [ant task](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html) to run checkstyle.

You should look at the [available checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html) to see if there is already a check that fulfills your requirement. If not, the following [guide](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) should have enough information to get you started.

Comment: I found the documentation you're pointing to but I still have questions.  I know the check I would like to create does not exist.  Do I still need the properties file in my taskdef?  Can you write out a working example?

Comment: You might be better off writing the task as a java ant task than a checkstyle task, as it more closely mimics the provided example.

Comment: Thanks for the response Edwin.  Have you done this before?  Can you write up an answer so I can try it and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a 'HelloWorld' style example although it is written for Maven and not Ant.

For an Ant build you would build the `BlundellCheckstyle` as a jar and package it in your /libs/ folder. The configuration is just the same as below and the command to run checkstyle from the command line would work a treat. Using the [AntTask](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html) example it looks pretty much like the Maven config and wouldn't take much to change it.

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/create-your-own-checkstyle-check/

and source code here:

https://github.com/blundell/CreateYourOwnCheckStyleCheck