# Creating a Custom Checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have another StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590429/java-checkstyle-usage) on how to install and run a custom checkstyle.  I've learned how to do this, and I will update that answer shortly with detailed instructions.  Now I am having trouble customizing my check.  Below is my code.  The problem is I would like to see the fully qualified package as a string (e.g `com.amir.foo`) - but instead when I run `getText()` or just `toString()`, I get some obscure result ([checkstyle] package set to : ANNOTATIONS).  Does anyone know how to work with this to achieve the desired results?

```
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.*;

public class MyCheck extends Check
{

    FullIdent packageDeclaration;

    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[]{TokenTypes.PACKAGE_DEF};
    }

    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast)
    {

        switch(ast.getType()) {
            case TokenTypes.PACKAGE_DEF:
                System.out.println("got package!");
                visitPackage(ast);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("naughty!");
        }

    }

    private void visitPackage(DetailAST pack) {
        packageDeclaration = FullIdent.createFullIdentBelow(pack);
        System.out.println("package set to : " +packageDeclaration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your looking for is used by the check for package names, you should use a code similar to the following:

```
@Override
public void visitToken(DetailAST aAST)
{
    final DetailAST nameAST = aAST.getLastChild().getPreviousSibling();
    final FullIdent full = FullIdent.createFullIdent(nameAST);
    final String package = full.getText();


    // do some fancy stuff with package name
}
```

For more details please refer to the source code of PackageNameCheck:
http://checkstyle.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/checkstyle/checkstyle/file/cd352660c53a/src/checkstyle/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/naming/PackageNameCheck.java

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Can you explain what this code is doing?  Why do we getLastChild then getPreviousSibling?

Comment: As a side note, this code will not compile because you're using the package keyword in the code.